# Static resources with Spring configuration-class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My jsp loads some additional file like css and js files like almost every website does with something like this:

```
<script src="js/dhtmlx/dhtmlx.js"></script>
```

The problem now is, that Spring wants to dispatch the request and isn't finding a proper handler for it, which is right. I tried the following in my config-class:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/");
}
```

which is not working, spring still wants to dispatch the request:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [...URI/js/dhtmlx/dhtmlx.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'keza'
```

How can I tell spring that this is not a request which the framework should dispatch with the dispatcherServlet?

Comment: You have "js/..." not "/js/..." or "/context/js/...".

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I changed it - but still the same error.

Comment: Could you show the class declaration in which you override `addResourceHandlers`, it looks like it was ignored by Spring ... and what exactly is the error when you use `src="/js/...` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure your js folder is available under src\main\webapp\resources

Comment: WebContent/resources/js/... ? Is that okay? I would change it to that

Comment: that's fine now try to access it like @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    } also change <script src="js/dhtmlx/dhtmlx.js"></script> to <script src="resources/js/dhtmlx/dhtmlx.js"></script>

Comment: can you share your directory structure

Comment: here [link]http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/zwischenablage0zt9b8f26nm.jpg[/link] you can see a screenshot

Comment: Not able to access image using above link. It shows message image is deleted or moved.

Comment: img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/zwischenablage0zt9b8f26nm.jpg

Comment: is your Webcontent is in your classpath

Comment: please explain. I am not sure.

Comment: thank you. But the tutorial shows exactly what I currently have. Which is leading to the excpetion that the dispatcher servlet tries to dispatch the request

Answer (score 1):

**1.Using mvc resources**

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/public-resources/"/>
```

This enables serving any static content whose location can be specified as a Spring [Resource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources)

**2. Using mvc:default-servlet-handler:**

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
```

This provides a way to serve out the static content from the root of the web application even though the Dispatcher Servlet is registered at /, the details of how Spring does this is available at the Spring documentation site here - in brief the responsibility is delegated to the containers default servlet.

**MVC resources using spring annotations**

```
@Configuration  
@EnableWebMvc  
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {  

        @Override  
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {  
                registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/public-resources/");  
        }  
}
```

Comment: should I add this in the dispatcher Servlet?

Comment: yup, you need to add this to your dispatcher-servlet.xml file.

Comment: i dont have a .xml-servlet anymore. That's what my question is about: How to express it in a config-class

Comment: I have added class configuration to above answer

Comment: That's exactly how i tried it. Doesn't work, plus i need to add @ComponentScan to the config class, otherwise i get multiple exceptions regarding instatiating beans